# principal components of mutual covariance marix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, covariance

[Principal component analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) basically takes the longest eingenvectors $\vec u_i$ of [covariacne matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) $C_{ij}= \sum_k X_{ki} X_{kj} $  where $X_{ki}$ is $i$-th component of $k$-th data sample from some dataset $X$.

I'm interested if there is something similar possible to do for mutual covariance matrix $M_{ij}= \sum_k X_{ki} Y_{kj} $ where $X$ and $Y$ are different datasets (of the same dimension, if it makes situation easier).

While principal components of $C_{ij}$ says how big is change $x_j$ on change of $x_i$ (i.e. correlation between two components of data from dataset $X$), it would say how big is change of $y_j$ on change of $x_i$ (i.e. correlation between component of data samples from dataset $X$ and an other component of data samples from dataset $Y$ ).

Comment: Do you know about [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)?

Comment: Maybe you could use the mutual covariance matrix as your data set

Comment: I think that the only thing you should care about is the positive definiteness, I think that @Omnomnomnom is right.

Comment: Yes, I know SVD, my question is if it still works (either with SVD or with eingenvalue decompostion ) even in case when the cross correlation matrix is not self adjoint ( which I guess is not when $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary matrixes  ), so I guess it is also not necesarlily positive definite. But maybe there is some way how to make it positive definite and still capture the information about correlations like using SVD of  $ M^T M $ instead of $M$ ??